# How do I display links based on user's role and reference?

Tags: forms, entities, users

I am building an evaluation platform in Drupal using either entity forms or webform. Attendees will evaluate the course, instructor, and location of the lab/site.

"Entities" are:

- **courses**: which is divided to many sections.

  - courses can be labs or lecture
- **instructors**: can have many courses and lab sites
- **sections**: can belong to only one individual course.
- **attendees**: can belong to many sections. They will evaluate the instructor, course, and lab site.

**Process**
Attendees will see a link of evaluation form to their respective course section after logging in to their profile page. The form will include course name, instructors name and lab site (if any).

**Progress:** 
I have the webform/form part down. My only issue is automatically assigning users to correct forms.

**Blocker**
But how do I automatically assign users to correct section (i.e. Attendee will evaluate instructor and lab site, or instructor alone if he/she was not assigned to lab). We're speaking of few hundred sections and attendees... Creating roles for few hundred sections is exhausting and flawed by design. Organic Groups does not seem to serve this purpose.

Should I create several entities of Lab Site, Instructors, Sections? And use entity reference to add individual forms? Attendees only allowed to submit evaluations to the courses they attended. I am not sure how to approach automation and assignment part. Another approach I am thinking is to add the course/section as reference profile field...

Additional Process: attendees list will pre-created before they login...

Any pointers would be helpful... Thanks!